# Algorithm for every possible tower built

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to create a program in C, which should do following:
Given *n* non zero, positive numbers, I am to print out all the towers, that can be built by given pieces. Only one rule - can't stack bigger onto smaller (but can stack two same sized). So, if I am given 3 numbers, 1 2 3, the possibilities are:

```
3, 2, 1
3, 1
3, 2
3
2, 1
2
1
```

given 2 2 3, its:

```
3, 2, 2
3, 2
3
2, 2
2
```

Can anyone help me, please? I tried looking into recursive algorithms, into Tower of Hanoi algorithm and related, but I am not able to think this out.

Comment: Sort the array by size. Then (hint) you can only stack 'right' array elements on 'left' ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by sorting the pieces in descending order of size, which means that the largest piece comes first. Now consider each sequence of identical pieces.

1. Let's say that we are currently looking at pieces of size `a`. Put all such pieces onto the tower.
2. Move on to the next largest size (pieces of size `b` such that `b < a`), and recursively build all possible towers from this point.
3. Is there at least one piece of size `a` on the tower? If so, remove one piece of size `a` and return to step 2.

The following program implements this algorithm in ANSI C. The user enters the pieces on the command line. We call `qsort` with the comparison function `reverse` to sort the input in descending order, and then we call the recursive function `print_tower`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Assumes that data is sorted in descending order. */
void print_tower(int *data, int n, int pos, int *result, int len) {
  int seek, i;
  /* If we're out of data, print the result pieces. */
  if (pos == n) {
    if (len > 0) {
      printf("%d", result[0]);
      for (i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        printf(", %d", result[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    return;
  }
  /* Scan the sequence of identical elements. */
  seek = pos;
  while (seek < n && data[seek] == data[pos]) {
    result[len++] = data[seek++];
  }
  /* Recursively print the tower and shorten the sequence. */
  while (pos++ <= seek) {
    print_tower(data, n, seek, result, len--);
  }
}

/* Comparison function to sort integers in descending order. */
int reverse(const void *p, const void *q) {
  int a = *(int *)p, b = *(int *)q;
  return b - a;
}

int main(int argc, char **args) {
  int i, n = argc-1,
      *data = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int)),
      *result = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    data[i] = atoi(args[i+1]);
  }
  qsort(data, n, sizeof(int), reverse);
  print_tower(data, n, 0, result, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, the problem can be simplified by sorting. If the array of numbers is sorted first, the problem reduces to the output of all sub-arrays of the input. If `n` denotes the number of elements in the input, this results in `2^n` possible sub-arrays which can be enumerated recursively.

However, this solution requires pieces of equal size in the input to be considered different. If pieces of equal size are considered to be equal, the input should be sorted and then converted to pairs `(s_i,m_i)` where `s_i`  denotes the size of the `i`-th piece and `m_i` denotes its multiplicity. Then, possible solutions can be generated using the following algorithm in pseudocode.

```
type piece = struct (integer, integer)

function enumerate( a array of piece )
{
    if ( a is empty )
    {
        end current solution
    }
    else
    {
        let f = first element of a
        for each i <= multiplicity of f
        {
            output size of f i times
            enumerate ( a with first element removed )
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's someone's mistake; your answer doesn't have any downvotes now >o<

Comment: This seems like legitimate solution, however the latter is simpler, but thanks, I'll look into it too for learning purposes :)